# Create view in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new in MVC. I have a ADD item Form (create view in MVC5) for an inventory system. If they want to create more than one of same items using the same form in same submission, can that be done? The problem is an inventory created for each record added. Any help is appreciated.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: yes it can be done, but you need to structure the form differently, so that the user can add a dynamic number of items - effectively you end up needing script to add the same set of fields again and again (using array syntax for the field name attribute in the HTML, so it submits a list). And the action method will also need amending to accept (and then save) a list of items, instead of a single one. So you can't use the exact same form to achieve your requirement, no - it needs significant modifications.

Comment: Do you have any example code/implementation?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. You asked if it's possible, and I answered the question. But you can google examples of how to create a form where you can submit a list. Then you can adapt it for your situation. If you get stuck, ask a question here about the specific issues in your code. That's what this site is for.

Comment: Asking for whole solutions or examples of a big feature like this is generally regarded as being too broad, and thus off-topic - there are too many ways it could be implemented, and it would take a long time to create a working answer - more time than it's worth for a few reputation points. We normally try to answer specific questions about problems or queries inside some existing code.